# Calculate number of records that satisfy the condition of 5 different Dates, in Excel, from Data Source

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have very awkward database(4mln rows), structured like this:

```
id, start     , suspension, renewal   , stop      , delete    , category
1,  01-01-2019, 01-02-2019, 01-03-2019, 01-04-2019, 02-04-2019, A    
2,  01-01-2019,           ,           , 01-04-2019, 02-04-2019, B
```

I can create nice Pivot Table, with date of lets say "suspension" as Column, number of unique id's as Values, Category as filter, and then see how many Items were suspended each day.

But I need to see as well, how many Items were active each day - that means Started, not Stopped or Deleted, and Renewed if Suspended.
Unfortunately it is not as simple as "substract number of deleted from started each day".

So when I filter category A in pivot table, Excel checks every record if `category == "A"`, right?
Can I do something similar, to check if `start <= date & (stop or delete >= date) & if(suspension <= date){renewal <= date}` for each row, for each date?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a calculated field. U can put the formula almost directly in there. May need some tweaking.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/calculate-values-in-a-pivottable-11f41417-da80-435c-a5c6-b0185e59da77

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible while using data model.

Comment: If you are using a data model as in DAX calculations you can add measures. Same basis principle.